# Java, accessing a swing element from a separate class

Tags: java, swing

just a quick question....

I am working in Java. I have 2 separate classes:

```
public class MulticastChatGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
}
```

and

```
public class MulticastThread extends Thread{
}
```

So, all I am really trying to do is to access an element from the GUI from within the Thread class, namely a Text Area. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for what is probably a very simple question.

Comment: If you are working with threads and a Swing UI, the best way to interact with the UI is through: [invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), and [invokeAndWait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29). These will execute a Runnable on the UI thread, which is the only way you should access Swing components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes, but it must be done with care.

For instance you could give your MulticastThread class a MulticastChatGUI variable, and then pass in a reference of the current MulticastChatGUI instance into the MulticastThread object via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

e.g.,

```
// constructor
public MulticastThread(MulticastChatGUI multicastChatGui) {
  this.multicastChatGui = multicastChatGui;
}

// or setter
public void setMulticastChatGUI(MulticastChatGUI multicastChatGui) {
  this.multicastChatGui = multicastChatGui;
}
```

Up to now, the problem and solution is the same for any program where you want one class to talk to another.

Care must be taken however that whenever you call a Swing method on the `JTextArea`, you do so only on the Swing event thread, else you risk occurrence of a pernicious, hard to debug, and intermittent threading exception.

Note that it is cleaner not to have one object access the other object's fields directly (here the `JTextArea`), but instead have the class with the `JTextArea` make it private, and give it public methods that allow outside classes to change its shape in a controlled manner.

Comment: Can the component's Class name be highlighted please? such as: `JTextArea` and similar. I wanted to edit, but thought you would mind.